# Make accordion responsive - Currently scrolls down list instead of being responsive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I cannot seem to make this happen and need someone to look at my code. I need the FAQ Accordion to be responsive. When it first loads collapsed the space where it would be open up is all blank. I need it to be responsive and make more room when opened up. Also when it opens it only has enough space to read the questions. When you open the last question for the answer it looks like it did not open, but you have to scroll down to see it. I need this to be responsive.

I am using an iframe to embed this on the website. Here is the iframe:

```
<p align="center"><iframe width="90%" height="450"  align="center" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/embed/2166736/fullscreen" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe></p>
```

Link to snippet: [Accordion V5](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/capitalit/2166736)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ILCA Accordion</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample275" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card z-depth-0">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne"> 
      <h5 class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne2 collapseOne3" data-parent="accordionExample275" style="font-size:20px" >       
          <p id="text">Still Have More Questions? We Have More Answers.</p>  
            <div class="center">
            <button class="button1 button1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="collapseOne1" data-target=".multi-collapse"
               aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne2 collapseOne3">View FAQ</button>
          </div>
       </button>
      </h5>
    </div> 
        <h5>
         <div class="collapse multi-collapse" >
            <button class="btn1 btn-link" role="tab" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="collapseOne2" data-target="#collapseOne3"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne3" style="font-size:20px">      
        What is your vision?
         </button>
        </div>
      </h5>
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse">
      <div id="collapseOne3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-parent="#accordionExample275" data-toggle="collapse" role="tabpanel">
      <div class="card-body" style="font-size:20px">
        World health transformed through breastfeeding and skilled lactation care.
      </div>
        </div>
       </div> 
        <h5>
         <div class="collapse multi-collapse" >
            <button class="btn1 btn-link" role="tab" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="collapseOne4" data-target="#collapseOne5"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne5" style="font-size:20px">      
        What is your vision?
         </button>
        </div>
      </h5>
     <div class="collapse multi-collapse">
      <div id="collapseOne5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-parent="#accordionExample275" data-toggle="collapse" role="tabpanel">
      <div class="card-body" style="font-size:20px">
        World health transformed through breastfeeding and skilled lactation care.
      </div>
         </div> 
        <h5>
         <div class="collapse multi-collapse" >
            <button class="btn1 btn-link" role="tab" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="collapseOne6" data-target="#collapseOne7"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne7" style="font-size:20px">      
        What is your vision?
         </button>
        </div>
      </h5>
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse">
      <div id="collapseOne7" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-parent="#accordionExample275" data-toggle="collapse" role="tabpanel">
      <div class="card-body" style="font-size:20px">
        World health transformed through breastfeeding and skilled lactation care.
      </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
.button1 {
  background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  padding: 1% 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
   margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: static;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  align-content: center;
  padding: 10 10 10 10;

}
.card-header {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
.btn {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3f516c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-style: none;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn:visited {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3f516c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-style: none;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn:focus {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3f516c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-style: none;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn:hover {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3f516c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-style: none;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn:active {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3f516c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-style: none;
    align-content: center;
}

p:hover {

opacity:1.0;
box-shadow:none;

}

.btn1 {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px
    padding-left: 20px
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;      
}


.btn1, .btn1:hover, .btn1:active, .btn1:visited, .btn1:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#collapseOne3 {border-bottom: 1px solid black;text-align: left; padding-left: auto}
#collapseOne5 {border-bottom: 1px solid black;text-align: left; padding-left: auto}
#collapseOne7 {border-bottom: 1px solid black;text-align: left; padding-left: auto}

#collapseOne2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
#collapseOne4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}

#collapseOne6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}

.headingOne {
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this using Java. Code is below.

*Java script where iFrame is created

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // Size the parent iFrame
  function iframeResize() {
    var height = $('body').outerHeight(); // IMPORTANT: If body's height is set to 100% with CSS this will not work.
    parent.postMessage("resize::"+height,"*");
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Resize iframe
    setInterval(iframeResize, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

*Java script for iFrame insertion

```
<p align="center"><iframe width="80%" scrolling="no" src='https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/embed/2166736/fullscreen' id='edh-iframe'></iframe></p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // Listen for messages sent from the iFrame
  var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

  eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    // If the message is a resize frame request
    if (e.data.indexOf('resize::') != -1) {
      var height = e.data.replace('resize::', '');
      document.getElementById('edh-iframe').style.height = height+'px';
    }
  } ,false);
</script>
```